# How to send parameters using Guzzle client in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I'm trying to do some application tests using phpunit and guzzle. The problem is when I set up my request and I post it, it losses almost all its data.

That's how my request looks:

```
$client->request(
                'POST',
                'catalogue/item/save',
                [
                    'json' => ['itemData' => [
                        'basic'=>[
                            'code'=>1
                        ]
                    ]],
                    'headers' => [
                        'X-AUTH-API-TOKEN'=>'Bearer '.$tokens->token,
                        'itemData'=>["asd"]
                        ],
                    'itemData' => ["asd"],
                    'request' => [
                        'itemData' => [
                            'basic'=>[
                                'code'=>1
                            ]
                        ]
            ]
                ]
            );
```

I know it looks chaotic but I tried every single way to pass the `itemData` array.

This is how I try to get `itemData` out of the request

```
$itemData = $request->request->get('itemData');
```

But it's always `null` since the `$request->request` is empty.

If I try `$request->getContents()` it has `'json'` array, but I can't change the method since I'm only testing it.

Does anyone have ideas what could be the problem causing `$request->request` to be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending any parameters.

`request` is not a [request option](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html).

You are looking for [`form_params`](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params), most likely.

Also, consider that `form_params` is not compatible with `json`. You either send one or the other. Since you are already sending `json`, you'll have to remove that from the request.

```php
$client->request(
    'POST',
    'catalogue/item/save',
    [

        'headers'     => [
            'X-AUTH-API-TOKEN' => 'Bearer ' . $tokens->token,
            'itemData'         => ["asd"],
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'itemData' => [
                'basic' => [
                    'code' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Comment: I swear to god I tried form_params, and it did not work, now I tried it again and it works.. Thanks ;D

Comment: It probably didn't work because you are sending `json` at the same time. As mentioned in the answer, that's not compatible (since `json` and `form_params` both use the request body to send the data)